# SQL Injection when not using variables

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-injection

Do I still need to protect my code against SQL injection when I'm not using variables in SQL queries?

Is this code still vulnerable?:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT subsubcat_name FROM subsubcategories WHERE subcat_ID = 4");
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['subsubcat_name'];
echo '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the SQL query is just a fixed string, there is no chance for SQL injection.

However, the way you print the output is a concern, because you fail to escape it for HTML.  For example, if one of the `subsubcat_name`s contains a `<` character, then it might be interpreted as an HTML tag.

In the worst case, if `subsubcat_name` contains a malicious string like `<script>while (true) alert("Ha ha");</script>`, it would be executed by the browser as JavaScript.  Cross-site scripting attacks like that can be used, for example, to steal login credentials.

To prevent such accidental or malicious breakage, you should call [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars):

```
echo htmlspecialchars($row['subsubcat_name']);
```

Even if the `subsubcat_name`s are not under user control, it's still good programming practice to ensure correctness by escaping all HTML output as HTML.

Comment: [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/function.htmlspecialchars.php) should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

it is not necessary for queries without external variable may have a protection against sql injection because the exploit is from a user or public inputed content only.

Your example is a select query there is no variable from outside so it is OK.